# Create MySQL server on a subdomain

Tags: mysql, port, load-balancing

Is it possible to split the instance of a dedicated box to serve mySQL on a seperate host. Example:

- www.site.com - ip 192.1.1.1
- mysql1.site.com - ip 192.1.1.2

and then I can host mySQL on this seperate subdomain server even do:

```
$dbhost="mysql1.site.com";
```

or

```
$dbhost="mysql1.site.com:3001";
// i dont know how to make ports
```

I have seen people do this, in once instance have

1. mysql1.site.com
2. mysql2.site.com
3. mysql3.site.com

where mysql1 is copied per 30seconds to 2 and 3, and if 1 fails, 2 and 3 are ready for backup..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is fully possible. You have two servers: one runs application, the other runs MySql database. Your application connects to the server running the database. No big deal.

For example on Amazon AWS the usual configuration is to run your application on Amazon EC2 server and your database on Amazon RDS server.

Comment: Can I do it ONE box though. Make a subdomain use a dynamic IP via dns?

Comment: Like look at this: $dsn = 'mysql://user:pass@localhost/openid';

Comment: let's say site.com and mysql.site.com domains both point to the same box. there is mysql and http server runing on that box. Yes, you can run both on the same box.

Comment: cool, we need to offer a service button hear to say "Hire Vilius Pau" now to provide this solution.

Answer (score 1):

if you need to sandbox mysql on one host then head over to http://mysqlsandbox.net/ not suited for production though so if you have one box and need multiple installations you can look in to virtualization as well

Answer (score 1):

Yes. You can have your `mysqld` on a different server than the `httpd`. And, yes, you can set up database replication.

Comment: Can you automatically have it sync database replication to two or three instances ? And more so, can you select different databases depending on use IP like load balancing? Is it server intense do to replicate every 1 second?

Comment: @TheBlackBenzKid: Stack Overflow is not really the best place for this discussion. You are looking for a chatroom where you can have an iterative discussion on the very broad realm of database systems management. Stack Overflow is for specific questions about specific things; yours is about as specific as "how do I survive? what can I eat? what can't I eat? what temperature range will my body tolerate? can I smoke pot?"